# Swift UICollectionView dequeuereusablecell duplicates previous cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView that displays the days of the week Monday through Sunday. If I modify the data in one cell (add a UIView to it for example), when I scroll over to another cell, that UIView appears in another cell as well. To be more precise, any change I make in the Monday cell for example is also made to the Thursday cell and then again in the Sunday cell. I think Swift is just reusing the first three cells over and over, since Monday, Thursday, and Sunday are all connected; Tuesday and Friday are connected; and Wednesday and Saturday are connected. Is there anyway to prevent that? Maybe specify a certain minimum number of cells to create before reusing?

Comment: The cells are reused and cached. so before using them AGAIN you need to prepare them. check the link of the  answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse

set your views to nil when you call prepareforreuse method in cell file

Example:

```
imageView.image = nil
```